# multiple value not insert into database

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, ajax

there i want to insert multiple family memeber datials into table but there is is some error the error are..

```
Notice: Undefined index: family_member_first_name_1 in C:\wamp64\www\finalproject\hrms(entigrity)\jobseek\index3.php on line 176
Notice: Undefined index: family_member_middle_name_1 in C:\wamp64\www\finalproject\hrms(entigrity)\jobseek\index3.php on line 177
```

and .......

```
 Notice: Undefined index: family_member_nomination_ratio_1 in C:\wamp64\www\finalproject\hrms(entigrity)\jobseek\index3.php on line 186..
```

there i 5 family member detaild insert so error will be come 5 times...
here the code is

```
<?php
include "config.php";
if(isset($_POST['family_member_btn'])) {

             $family_member = $_POST['family_member']; 

}

if(isset($_POST["submit4"])) {

    if($_SESSION['email']) {

        $db->where('primary_email',$_SESSION['email']);
        $email_fetch_femily = $db->getone('om_user_list_a');
            if($email_fetch_femily) {

                $fetch_id_family = $email_fetch_femily['id'];
            }

            $cnt_row = $_POST["num"]; 

            for($i=1; $i<=$cnt_row; $i++) {

                    $data5 = array(
                        "user_id" => $fetch_id_family,
                        "first_name" => $_POST['family_member_first_name_'.$i],
                        "middle_name" => $_POST['family_member_middle_name_'.$i],
                        "last_name" => $_POST['family_member_last_name_'.$i],
                        "birth_date" => $_POST['family_member_birth_date_'.$i],
                        "relative_type" => $_POST['family_member_relation_'.$i],
                        "marital_status" => $_POST['family_member_merital_status_'.$i],
                        "education_status" => $_POST['family_member_education_'.$i],
                        "occupation" => $_POST['family_member_occupation_'.$i],
                        "phone" => $_POST['family_member_phone_'.$i],
                        "gratuity_ratio" => $_POST['family_member_gratuity_ratio_'.$i],
                        "nomination_ratio" => $_POST['family_member_nomination_ratio_'.$i],
                        "status" => 1,
                        "created_by" => $fetch_id_family,
                        "created_date" =>  date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                        "created_ip" => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
                    );

                        $insert_family_details = $db->insert("om_relative_list",$data5);
                            if($insert_family_details) {
                                echo "<script>alert('family details insert successfully');</script>";
                            } else {                        
                                echo "<script>alert('!!!!family deatis insert unsuccessfully');</script>";
                            }



            }




    }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>


<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>Pages - Admin Dashboard UI Kit - Form Wizard</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, shrink-to-fit=no"/>
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="pages/ico/60.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="pages/ico/76.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="pages/ico/120.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="pages/ico/152.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico"/>
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-touch-fullscreen" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="default">
<meta content="" name="description"/>
<meta content="" name="author"/>
<link href="assets/plugins/pace/pace-theme-flash.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="assets/plugins/bootstrapv3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="assets/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="assets/plugins/jquery-scrollbar/jquery.scrollbar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
<link href="assets/plugins/switchery/css/switchery.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
<link href="pages/css/pages-icons.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link class="main-stylesheet" href="pages/css/pages.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<!--[if lte IE 9]>
    <link href="assets/plugins/codrops-dialogFx/dialog.ie.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body class="fixed-header ">

<div id="rootwizard" class="m-t-50">

<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-tabs-linetriangle nav-tabs-separator nav-stack-sm">
  <li class="">
<a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab4"><span>FAMILY DETAILS</span></a>
</li>
</ul>
<form  method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="tab-pane slide-left padding-20" id="tab4">
<div class="row row-same-height">
<div class="col-md-5 b-r b-dashed b-white ">

</div>
<div class="col-md-12">

<div class="padding-30" >

        <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="col-sm-9">
        <div class="form-group form-group-default">
        <label><font size="2">HOW MANY MEMBER IN YOUR FAMILY ?</font></label>
        <input type="text" name="family_member" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
        <button type="submit" name="family_member_btn" class="btn btn-lg btn-info"  style="padding:11pt;width:200px;"/><span><b><font size="2">SUBMIT</font></b></span></button>
        </div>
        </div><br><br>
        <?php
            for($i=1;$i<=$family_member;$i++) {

        ?>
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $family_member;?>" name="num" >
        <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="form-group form-group-default">
        <label><font size="2">First Name</font></label>
        <input type="text" name="family_member_first_name[]" class="form-control"   />
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="form-group form-group-default ">
        <label><font size="2">Middle Name</font></label>
        <input type="text" name="family_member_middle_name[]" class="form-control"  >
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="form-group form-group-default ">
        <label><font size="2">Last name</font></label>
        <input type="text" name="family_member_last_name[]" class="form-control"  />
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>  

        <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="form-group form-group-default ">
        <label><font size="2">birthdate</font></label>
        <input id="datepicker3" class="form-control" name="family_member_birth_date[]" type="text" />
        </div>
        </div>  
        <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="form-group form-group-default form-group-default-selectFx">
        <label><font size="2">Realation</font></label>
        <select class="cs-select cs-skin-slide cs-transparent form-control" name="family_member_relation[]" data-init-plugin="cs-select">
        <option value=""></option>
        <?php
        $db->where('type_id','4');
        $Industry=$db->get('om_master_values'); 
        foreach($Industry as $indu){
        ?>
        <option  value="<?php echo $indu['id'] ?>" ><?php echo $indu['master_values'] ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
        </select>
        </div>
        </div>  
        <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="form-group form-group-default  form-group-default-selectFx">
        <label><font size="2">MARITAL STATUS</font></label>
        <select class="cs-select cs-skin-slide cs-transparent form-control" name="family_member_merital_status[]" data-init-plugin="cs-select">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="married">MARRIED</option>
        <option value="unmarried">UNMARRIED</option>
        </select>
        </div>
        </div>              
        </div>

        <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="form-group form-group-default form-group-default-selectFx">
        <label><font size="2">EDUCATION</font></label>
        <select class="cs-select cs-skin-slide cs-transparent form-control" name="family_member_education[]" data-init-plugin="cs-select">
        <option value=""></option>
        <?php
        $db->where('type_id','5');
        $Industry=$db->get('om_master_values'); 
        foreach($Industry as $indu){
        ?>
        <option  value="<?php echo $indu['id'] ?>" ><?php echo $indu['master_values'] ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
        </select>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="form-group form-group-default">
        <label><font size="2">occupation</font></label>
        <input type="text" name="family_member_occupation[]" class="form-control"  />
        </div>
        </div>  
        <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="form-group form-group-default">
        <label><font size="2">PHONE</font></label>
        <input type="text" name="family_member_phone[]" class="form-control"  />
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="form-group form-group-default">
        <label><font size="2">gratuity_ratio</font></label>
        <input type="text" name="family_member_gratuity_ratio[]" class="form-control"  />
        </div>
        </div>  
        <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="form-group form-group-default">
        <label><font size="2">nomination_ratio</font></label>
        <input type="text" name="family_member_nomination_ratio[]" class="form-control"  />
        </div>
        </div>          
        </div>

        <hr style="border:solid 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);">
        <?php } ?>




</div><br><br>
<div class="padding-20">
<button class="btn btn-info  btn-cons from-left  pull-right" type="submit" name="submit4">
<span>SUBMIT</span>
</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="tab-pane slide-left padding-20" id="tab5">
<div class="row row-same-height">
<div class="col-md-5 b-r b-dashed b-grey ">
<div class="padding-30 m-t-50">


</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="tab-pane slide-left padding-20" id="tab6">
<div class="row row-same-height">
<div class="col-md-5 b-r b-dashed b-grey ">



</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="tab-pane slide-left padding-20" id="tab7">
<div class="row row-same-height">
<div class="col-md-5 b-r b-dashed b-grey ">

</div>
</div>
</div>


</form>
</div>
</div>



<script src="assets/plugins/pace/pace.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/plugins/jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/plugins/modernizr.custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/plugins/bootstrapv3/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/plugins/jquery/jquery-easy.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/plugins/jquery-unveil/jquery.unveil.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/plugins/jquery-bez/jquery.bez.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/plugins/jquery-ios-list/jquery.ioslist.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/plugins/jquery-actual/jquery.actual.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/plugins/jquery-scrollbar/jquery.scrollbar.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/classie/classie.js"></script>
<script src="assets/plugins/switchery/js/switchery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/plugins/bootstrap3-wysihtml5/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.all.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/jquery-autonumeric/autoNumeric.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/bootstrap-tag/bootstrap-tagsinput.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/jquery-inputmask/jquery.inputmask.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/plugins/bootstrap-form-wizard/js/jquery.bootstrap.wizard.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/plugins/jquery-validation/js/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/plugins/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/plugins/summernote/js/summernote.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/plugins/moment/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/plugins/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<script src="assets/plugins/bootstrap-timepicker/bootstrap-timepicker.min.js"></script>


<script src="pages/js/pages.min.js"></script>

  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker();
  });
  </script>
    <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#datepicker2").datepicker();
  });
  </script>
      <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#datepicker3").datepicker();
  });
  </script>

<script src="assets/js/form_wizard.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/js/scripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="assets/js/demo.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
         window.intercomSettings = {
           app_id: "xt5z6ibr"
         };
</script>


</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Please explain your `HTML` code for better understand.

Comment: there is i input number of family member so there create table for each family member .......and i insert those at same time and in one query also in particular user id

Answer (score 2):

In your html you are using arrays:

```
<input type="text" name="family_member_first_name[]" class="form-control"   />
                                                 ^^ array in input name
```

So in your php you need to check your POST variables using arrays as well.

So:

```
"first_name" => $_POST['family_member_first_name_'.$i],
// etc.
```

needs to be:

```
"first_name" => $_POST['family_member_first_name'][$i],
// etc.
```

**Edit:** You seem to be using a POST variable to get the number of items in the arrays. I haven't checked how you set that, but the safest option would be to simply count the number of items in one of the arrays (this won't work for checkboxes...).

And you need to start at `0`, not `1`.

So change:

```
for($i=1; $i<=$cnt_row; $i++) {
```

to:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['family_member_first_name']); $i++) {
```

Comment: i try this but errors will be Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in C:\wamp64\www\finalproject\hrms(entigrity)\jobseek\index3.php on line 176..................Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in C:\wamp64\www\finalproject\hrms(entigrity)\jobseek\index3.php on line 186........

Comment: how can i solve it

Comment: any one help me for this...??

Comment: @DharmeshMakwana See my edit.

Comment: error will be Notice: Undefined index: family_member_first_name in C:\wamp64\www\finalproject\hrms(entigrity)\jobseek\index3.php on line 172 after above code

Comment: any one help me